# stop bulma ribbons from overlaying content when printing

Tags: css, sass, printing, less, bulma

[image]

I am working on creating a research report. When I want to save the report as a pdf the navigation ribbon overlays the content. How can I avoid this?

I don't want to hide the ribbons with printing, but they should not overlay the content.

My current ribbons:

```
 <!-- top ribbon -->
  <nav id="navitop" class="navbar is-fixed-top">
    <div id="topc" class="columns">
      <div class="column is-12">
        <!-- disclaimer -->
        <h1 class="title disclaimer is-4">
          RESEARCH ONLY - <u>NOT</u> FOR CLINICAL USE
        </h1>
        <!-- disclaimer -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- bottom ribbon -->
  <nav id="navibottom" class="navbar is-fixed-bottom">
    <div id="botc" class="columns is-gapless is-vcentered">
      <div class="column is-4">
        {{ meta.readable_id }}
      </div>
      <div class="column is-4">
        <!-- disclaimer -->
        <h1 class="title disclaimer is-6">
          RESEARCH ONLY <br /><u>NOT</u> FOR CLINICAL USE
        </h1>
        <!-- disclaimer -->
      </div>
      <div class="column is-4">
        {{ meta.timestamp }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the specific classed for this situation to the html or body, [as described in the official docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#fixed-navbar).

```
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top has-navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

As-is, this does work only for the screen media.

To have a similar outcome on printed page media, you need to add specific classes at the page level,along these lines:

```
@page {
    body.has-navbar-fixed-bottom, html.has-navbar-fixed-bottom {
        padding-bottom: 5cm;
    }
    
    body.has-navbar-fixed-top, html.has-navbar-fixed-top {
        padding-top: 5cm;
    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: thanks, I tried what you suggested but it seems to have no effect. in G chrome pdf printing the ribbons still overlay content